# How ansible create dir without "T" right

Tags: directory, ansible, access-rights

When I create a dir with ansible, her rights is:

```
dr------wT"
```

Code:

```
- name: "Create Dir in opt"
  become: yes
  file:
    path: "/opt/test"
    state: directory
    mode: 770
    owner: test
    group: test
```

How create dir with simple rights?

```
drwxrwx---
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found:

Put 0 before 770

```
 mode: 0770
```

Thanks all!